# Dashboard login on wordpress 3.6 redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, authentication

-Fresh install on a bluehost shared account

-I have read the document with the proposed solutions found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble). Nothing worked.

When i hit: http://www.mydomain.com/wp-admin i get:

http://www.mydomain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fmydomain-com%2Fwww%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

it seems that it redirects me to the real subdirectory where my domain has the files. To achieve this my provider instructed to use this htaccess on the root of my accounts directory:

```
# Use PHP5.3 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53s .php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomain-com/www/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mydomain-com/www/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mydomain-com/www/index.php [L]
```

Some more info on the directory structure

www.mydomain.com is installed in /public_html/mydomain-com/www

wordpress is installed in the root of my www.mydomain.com thus: /public_html/mydomain-com/www

any ideas?

**EDIT**: The only way i find that works is to go directly to http://www.mydomain.com/wp-login.php

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution [here](http://www.gilluminate.com/2011/03/10/wp-admin-issues-with-hosting-a-primary-domain-from-a-subfolder-on-bluehost/)

The important stuff:

In WP directory's .htaccess file ,just below the line containing “RewriteEngine on”, add:

```
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/wp-admin$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
```